# Check if string exists in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

After looking through posts and using Google I think I have the basic components of my answer, although I'm not entirely sure how to put them together due to lack of experience with MySQL.

**---Edit Begin (2013/10/16@1110GMT---**
Here is how the code currently looks:

```
    $username="username"; $password="password"; $database="database";
    mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);@mysql_select_db($database) or die(
    "Unable to select database");

    $needle = 'sdfsdf';

    $checkUserID = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM order_option WHERE value LIKE '%$needle%' ");
    if (!$checkUserID) {
        die('Query failed to execute for some reason');
    }

    if (mysql_num_rows($checkUserId) > 0) {
        echo "<p>User id exists already.</p>";
        $user = mysql_fetch_array($checkUserId);
        print_r($user); // the data returned from the query
    }
    mysql_close();
```

I wonder if I may have misunderstood MySQL, though I understand that should pull the query from this MySQL
        TRUNCATE TABLE `order_option`;

```
    INSERT INTO `order_option` (`order_option_id`, `order_id`, `order_product_id`, `product_option_id`, `product_option_value_id`, `name`, `value`, `type`) VALUES ('13', '2', '2', '237', '0', 'Additional Information', 'sdfsdf', 'textarea');
    INSERT INTO `order_option` (`order_option_id`, `order_id`, `order_product_id`, `product_option_id`, `product_option_value_id`, `name`, `value`, `type`) VALUES ('14', '2', '2', '228', '0', 'Website', 'fsdfsd', 'text');
```

**---End of edit---**

The script is as follows:

```
$user="user"; $password="password"; $database="mydatabase";
mysql_connect(localhost,$user,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

$needle = 'sdfsdf';

$checkUserID = mysql_query("SELECT value from order_option WHERE value = '$needle'");
if (!$checkUserID) {
    die('Query failed to execute for some reason');
}

if (mysql_num_rows($checkUserId) > 0) {
    echo "User id exists already.";
    $user = mysql_fetch_array($checkUserId);
    print_r($user); // the data returned from the query
}

mysql_close();
```

If the above code is correct than I need to know how to use it along the lines of

```
if ($result == $needle) {
    echo('found'); 
} else { 
    echo('not found'); 
}
```

Comment: You need to check exact value are need to do search

Answer (score 0):

Your code already tests for the $needle to be found

```
if (mysql_num_rows($checkUserId) > 0) {
```

This little line looks for the number of results that match your query. If there are more than 0 (Inother words: If a match has been found!) it continues.

To match your request:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($checkUserId) > 0) 
  {
  echo "found";
  {
else
  {
  echo "not found";
  }
```

Comment: So I should use that to replace(?):
        if (mysql_num_rows($checkUserId) > 0) {
            echo "User id exists already.";
            $user = mysql_fetch_array($checkUserId);
            print_r($user); // the data returned from the query
        }